# Fit quadratic model by categories and estimate inflection point in R

Tags: r

I would like to ask you a question. I'm interested in fitting a second-order polynomial regression by category, and then calculating the inflection point in each of those regressions and categories.

The variable y is C3, the numeric regressor variable (x) is C2, and the categories are C1.

The database that I am using and the code is as follows. Thank you very much in advance, any help I will thank you very much!

```
df <- data.frame(C1=c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'),
         C2=c('1','2','3','4','2','4','5','6'),
         C3=c(10,20,25,15,20,60,60,20),
         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$C2<-as.numeric(df$C2)
df$C3<-as.numeric(df$C3)

model<-lm(C3~C1+(poly(C2,degree=2,raw=TRUE))+C1*(poly(C2,degree=2,raw=TRUE)), data = df)
```

[image]

Comment: The inflection point is where the first derivative equals zero.

Comment: I would need to generate a code to make it automatic. My original database contains 12000 data. Any information is of great help!

Comment: NB: In the formula, `lm(C3 ~ C1*poly(C2, degree=2, raw=TRUE), data=df)` is sufficient.

Comment: How to estimate the first derivate of adjusted values of my model, and then equals zero??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing's first let's look at the first derivative of the equation:

[image]

When `C1B=0` and you set it equal to zero and solve, you get the following:

[image]

So, the first derivative is the negative of the coefficient on the linear term divided by two times the coefficient on the squared term.  We can use this to identify the same quantities in R.

```
## get the coefficients from the model
b <- coef(model)

## find the ones that end with 1 (these are the coefficients on the linear term)
b1 <- b[grep("1$", names(b))]
## find the ones that end with 2 (these are the coefficients on the squared term)
b2 <- b[grep("2$", names(b))]
## put the two terms in a matrix
bmat <- cbind(b1, b2)
```

Now, the coefficients for the non-reference groups are the global coefficients plus the coefficients for that particular group.  So, the global coefficients are the effect for the reference group.  The

```
## coefficients for the reference group. 
comb.b <- bmat[1,]
for(i in 2:nrow(bmat)){
  ## make the coefficients for the non-reference groups
  comb.b <- rbind(comb.b, bmat[1,] + bmat[i,])
}
## calculate the inflection point
inf.point <- -comb.b[,1]/(2*comb.b[,2])
## attach category names
names(inf.point) <- levels(df$C1)
inf.point
#          A          B 
# 2.700000 4.033333
```

Comment: Excellent thanks! However, I don't understand the meaning of inf.point. I plotted the data and roughly the inflection points should be 3 and 4.5 for A and B respectively. Or am I looking wrong?

Comment: @Calfiao sorry - I had the 2 on the wrong side of the comma in the index to the `inf.point` object.  I've fixed it and corrected the output.  The `inf.point` object should contain the inflection points.